# Dropwizard upgrade from 0.7 to 0.8.0 release error

Tags: maven, dropwizard

I recently upgraded from 0.7 to 0.8 release version of dropwizard. Right out-of-the-box, I get the following error when I am trying to start my application. I have cleaned my maven repository and started fresh but still no luck.

```
INFO  [2015-03-11 20:03:45,144] io.dropwizard.server.ServerFactory: Starting CoreApplication
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpGenerator$CachedHttpField
        at io.dropwizard.server.AbstractServerFactory.buildServer(AbstractServerFactory.java:490)
        at io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory.build(DefaultServerFactory.java:155)
```

All help appreciated !

Comment: I've tried an upgrade of DW application from 0.7.0 to 0.8.0. It's the FrameworkBenchmark's Dropwizard test. Everything is fine besides some problems with the new ViewBundle configuration. So you should check your maven stuff (clean, install and local repository cleaning) again of maybe you have something in your DW configuration that is a problem. The reference for the configuration is here: http://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.8.0/docs/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have an old jetty dependency in your maven which doesn't match the one dropwizard 0.8 has, which should be `9.2.9.v20150224`.